# SIGABRT Error After Snippets Added to Source Code

Tags: iphone, sigabrt

So after adding the following snippets to my source code, the application refuses to run and gives me a SIGABRT error:

**CIALBrowserViewController.h**

```
UIBarButtonItem *homeButtonItem;
```

**CIALBrowserViewController.m**

```
@interface CIALBrowserViewController ()
- (void)goHome:(id)sender;
```

..

```
homeButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"]
                                                          style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                         target:self
                                                         action:@selector(goHome:)] autorelease];
```

..

```
- (void)goHome:(id)sender {
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.ca/"];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

**The SIGABRT Error**

```
2012-06-17 14:15:15.130 CIALBrowser[1753:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x354fa88f 0x378a1259 0x3544f1d7 0x5f8b 0x32f67c17 0x2a67 0x32f66cab 0x32f607dd 0x32f2eac3 0x32f2e567 0x32f2df3b 0x370ed22b 0x354ce523 0x354ce4c5 0x354cd313 0x354504a5 0x3545036d 0x32f5f86b 0x32f5ccd5 0x28df 0x2878)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Heres the full source code to CIALBrowserViewController.m: http://pastebin.com/uuUgi7Dc

Comment: What does the code look like where you are calling `insertObject:atIndex:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `else` section of `if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)`, there is no `homeButtonItem` alloced or inited, so `homeButtonItem` is nil. Then `[buttons addObject:homeButtonItem];` will crash, because you are adding a nil object to array.

Answer (score 0):

THe SIGABRT error suggests that somewhere in your code you use the method `insertObject:atIndex:` and use `nil` as the first parameter, which is not allowed, throwing an error. I went to your code on paste bin and did not see that method called there, so the error is likely in another file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Odd, I've searched through every file twice and nothing has shown. Also note that the error only comes up when adding the lines of code above in my questions.